# Overriding default functions in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

**Question:**
Can I override "default" functions in Javascript?

**Background:**
After figuring out that I had collisions between objects stored in `localStorage`, I decided that I should apply a prefix to all keys to avoid collisions.  Obviously, I could create a wrapper function, but it would  be so much neater to override the default `localStorage.getItem` & `localStorage.setItem` directly to take my prefix into account.

My example kills Firefox completely as it recursively calls itself, so it clearly isn't close to a solution. Perhaps it clarifies what I want to accomplish though.

**Code:**

```
Storage.prototype.setItem = function(key, value) {
    this.setItem("prefix"+key, value);
};

Storage.prototype.getItem = function(key, value) {
    return this.getItem("prefix"+key);
};
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to store the old function.

```
Storage.prototype._setItem = Storage.prototype.setItem;
Storage.prototype.setItem = function(key, value) {
    this._setItem("prefix" + key, value);
};

Storage.prototype._getItem = Storage.prototype.getItem;
Storage.prototype.getItem = function(key) {
    return this._getItem("prefix" + key);
};
```

If you don't, you get an infinite loop consuming stack space at every iteration, resulting in a stack overflow, crashing your browser :)

Comment: its both :) infinite recursion resulting in stack overflow! its possible to get stack overflow without infinite recursion :P

Comment: yes, that's true. but come on. this would fail because of a stack overflow. it it was an infinite loop, it wouldn't generate an JS error.

Comment: That's a clean solution. Thank you!

Comment: @PaulNikonowicz yes, unless the infinite loop consumes some resources. perhaps i should update my answer :) thanks

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, instead of creating a new variables to hold the old *Storage* functions you could always bind your functions like so.

```
Storage.prototype.setItem = (function(key, value) {
    this.call(localStorage,"prefix" + key, value);
}).bind(Storage.prototype.setItem);

Storage.prototype.getItem = (function(key) {
    return this.call(localStorage,"prefix" + key);
}).bind(Storage.prototype.getItem);
```

And you get the benefits of representing your new functions as *native code* when inspected in the console as well as a less cluttered code.

Comment: I used your answer because it looks like this can't be undone which is what I want. Is that true?

Comment: To my knowledge it can't.

Answer (score 1):

That is normal, you make a infinite recursion : in Storage.prototype.setItem, you call this.setItem that refers to Storage.prototype.setItem.

The same for Storage.prototype.getItem.