# Android: failed to override default local storage functions in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, android, webview, local-storage

I'd like to override default functions for local storage, and I did exactly follow the guide by [Overriding default functions in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9268461/overriding-default-functions-in-javascript).

However, the overridden functions only perfectly worked on Android 4.0+ (built-in browser), and both Chrome for Android and for desktop. On Android 2.3.x, these functions got resumed, for unknown reason, to default implementations after 10 seconds or so when page got loaded, in my test. 'Got remused' means I can't call my own SetItem/GetItem.

Did anybody run into same problem? Is it a bug or mis-function?